# How can I add icons to a map while using the function L.geoJSN on Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I know I can add icons on Leaflet using the following logic:

```js
const geojson = {
      "name": "interseccao_circulo",
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPoint",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                -46.62831244066412,
                -23.551014464955063
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPoint",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                -46.63242614612176,
                -23.55277865770234
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }

var mymap = L.map('mapdiv', {
center:[-23.552778, -46.632426],
    zoom:16,
    maxZoom:20,
    zoomControl:false,
    attributionControl:false
});
var lyrOSRHOT = L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap.HOT');
mymap.addLayer(lyrOSRHOT);

var icons = new L.Icon({
iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/ZcGeIVz.png",
iconSize: [40, 40],
});
let lat = geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][1]
let lng = geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][0]

let lat2 = geojson.features[1].geometry.coordinates[0][1]
let lng2 = geojson.features[1].geometry.coordinates[0][0]

L.marker([lat, lng], {icon: icons}).addTo(mymap);
L.marker([lat2, lng2], {icon: icons}).addTo(mymap);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet-src.min.js" integrity="sha512-XQr+/1RXvYozXiwrumwtu3lqQmVwZ8nkLUrC/mc3HBHw4Imh++RXjwtLQFuOz3i65j9CSfKt50x6w/uUY2ovOQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-providers/1.12.0/leaflet-providers.min.js" integrity="sha512-LixflAm9c0/qONbz9F1Ept+QJ6QBpb7wUlPuyv1EHloTVgwSK8j3yMV3elnElGQcv7Y5QTFlF/FqyeE/N4LnKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div id="mapdiv" style="height:100vh; width: 100vw"></div>
```

However, I'd like to make it work when I draw the points using the `L.geoJSON` function. Something like the following:

```js
const geojson = { 
    "name": "interseccao_circulo",
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -46.62831244066412,
                        -23.551014464955063
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -46.63242614612176,
                        -23.55277865770234
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]   
}   
var mymap = L.map('mapdiv', {
  center:[-23.552778, -46.632426],
    zoom:16,
    maxZoom:20,
    zoomControl:false,
    attributionControl:false
}); 
var lyrOSRHOT = L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap.HOT');
mymap.addLayer(lyrOSRHOT);
var icons = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/ZcGeIVz.png",
    iconSize: [40, 40],
});

L.geoJSON(geojson, {icon: icons} ).addTo(mymap);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet-src.min.js" integrity="sha512-XQr+/1RXvYozXiwrumwtu3lqQmVwZ8nkLUrC/mc3HBHw4Imh++RXjwtLQFuOz3i65j9CSfKt50x6w/uUY2ovOQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-providers/1.12.0/leaflet-providers.min.js" integrity="sha512-LixflAm9c0/qONbz9F1Ept+QJ6QBpb7wUlPuyv1EHloTVgwSK8j3yMV3elnElGQcv7Y5QTFlF/FqyeE/N4LnKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div id="mapdiv" style="height:100vh; width: 100vw"></div>
```

I've tried running it with `L.geoJSON(geojson, {icon: icons} ).addTo(mymap)`, but it doesn't seem to recognize `{icon: icons}` as the function `L.marker` does (it's plotting the default Leaflet marker instead)... Is there any way I can draw icons with the function `L.geoJSON` when I use LeafLet?

Comment: Read https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution to this problem using the `pointToLayer` object instead of trying to use the `icon` object inside `L.geoJSON`. As it's written on the [Leaflet geoJSON documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/), the accepted options inside it are only: `style`, `pointToLayer`, `onEachFeature` and `filter`. The `icon` option is not accepted inside the Leaflet `geoJSON` function and it should be used inside the `pointToLayer` object instead... The solution is the following:

```js
const geojson = {
    "name": "interseccao_circulo",
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -46.62831244066412,
                        -23.551014464955063
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -46.63242614612176,
                        -23.55277865770234
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

var mymap = L.map('mapdiv', {
  center:[-23.552778, -46.632426],
    zoom:16,
    maxZoom:20,
    zoomControl:false,
    attributionControl:false
});
var lyrOSRHOT = L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap.HOT');
mymap.addLayer(lyrOSRHOT);


L.geoJSON(geojson, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        const icons = new L.Icon({
            iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/ZcGeIVz.png",
            iconSize: [40, 40],
        });
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: icons});
    }
}).addTo(mymap);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet-src.min.js" integrity="sha512-XQr+/1RXvYozXiwrumwtu3lqQmVwZ8nkLUrC/mc3HBHw4Imh++RXjwtLQFuOz3i65j9CSfKt50x6w/uUY2ovOQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-providers/1.12.0/leaflet-providers.min.js" integrity="sha512-LixflAm9c0/qONbz9F1Ept+QJ6QBpb7wUlPuyv1EHloTVgwSK8j3yMV3elnElGQcv7Y5QTFlF/FqyeE/N4LnKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<div id="mapdiv" style="height:100vh; width: 100vw"></div>
```